# My PowerShell task scheduler script is showing a runtime exception error when running

Tags: powershell, exception, task, runtime, scheduled-tasks

When I run the following script to create a Scheduled Task, I receive the error

> Bad type(Exception de HRESULT : 0x80020005 (DISP_E_TYPEMISMATCH))

```
$u = "domain\$env:username" 
$p = "SomePassword"
$UserPass = ConvertTo-SecureString $p -AsPlainText -Force

$TaskName = "ML"
$TaskDescr = "Descriptor"
$TaskCommand = "$pos\$nm"
$TaskStartTime = [datetime]::Now.AddMinutes(5)
$service = new-object -ComObject("Schedule.Service")
$service.Connect()
$rtFr = $service.GetFolder("\")
$TaskDefinition = $service.NewTask(0)
$TaskDefinition.RegistrationInfo.Description = "$TaskDescr"
$TaskDefinition.Settings.Enabled = $true
$TaskDefinition.Settings.AllowDemandStart = $true
$triggers = $TaskDefinition.Triggers
$dd = "T"
$vv = "yyyy-MM-dd"
$xx = "HH:mm:ss"
$pr = "$vv$dd$xx"
$trigger = $triggers.Create(9)
$trigger.StartBoundary = $TaskStartTime.ToString($pr)
$trigger.Enabled = $true
$Action = $TaskDefinition.Actions.Create(0)
$action.Path = "$TaskCommand"
$rtFr.RegisterTaskDefinition("$TaskName",$TaskDefinition,6,$u,$UserPass,5)
```

Comment: A lot of COM objects can't be used in a non-interactive session. To be honest: I don't understand why you'd use a com object to create scheduled task since Powershell has some built in cmdlets to do this

Comment: It would be helpful to post the full error. Also, agreeing with Bluuf, why not use the built-in cmdlets? I.e.: `New-ScheduledTask`

Comment: Try `$trigger.StartBoundary = $TaskStartTime.ToString("o")` to use the [round-trip specifier](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-date-and-time-format-strings#Roundtrip). The `StartBoundary` property needs the date as string in format `yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss(+-)HH:MM`. See [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/taskschd/trigger-startboundary)

Comment: Thanks for you comment, the COM object is used because the built in cmdlet is not available on the windows 7 version i  try to make it work.

Comment: Since Windows 7 is out of support (and has been out of support for quite some time now) I'd really advise against using this OS. Besides the security aspects it also makes it harder to get help from people (especially when it comes down to code not working because of missing or outdated libraries)

Comment: You are right, i'll try do deal with it until they upgrade to Win 10 , maybe in 2 or 3 months 
Thanks for your answers

Answer (score 0):

There is too much to say about your script but let's focus on your issue:

**Exception from HRESULT: 0x80020005 (DISP_E_TYPEMISMATCH)**

This error is caused by the fact that **$rtFr.RegisterTaskDefinition** parameter for the password requires clear text, not encrypted string. So change your script as follow:

- Use $p instead of $UserPass
- Change trigger type from 9 to 1 (see below why)
- Change logon type from 5 to 6 (see below why)

Modifications:

```
# Change these lines
$trigger = $triggers.Create(9)
$rtFr.RegisterTaskDefinition("$TaskName",$TaskDefinition,6,$u,$UserPass,5)

# To this
$trigger = $triggers.Create(1)
$rtFr.RegisterTaskDefinition($TaskName,$TaskDefinition,6,$u,$p,6)
```

refs:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/taskschd/taskfolder-registertaskdefinition
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/taskschd/triggercollection-create

### This is enough for your script to be executed without errors

...

Now, if you don't change the **trigger type** from 9 to 1, you will encounter this error:

**Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED)**

You are trying to create a task that will be executed at logon (**$trigger = $triggers.Create(9)**), which requires administrative privileges. So you must run your script from an elevated Powershell session (run as Administrator)

And finally, if you don't change the **logon type** from 5 to 6, you will encounter this error:

**(XX,XX):UserId: At :XX char:XX**

You are trying to create a task with a logon type TASK_LOGON_SERVICE_ACCOUNT, without specifying which service account to use. Also you are passing username and password parameters to create the task, they should be empty/null.

```
# Change this line
$rtFr.RegisterTaskDefinition($TaskName,$TaskDefinition,6,$u,$p,6)

# To this
$TaskDefinition.Principal.UserId = "S-1-5-18" # i.e Local System Account
$rtFr.RegisterTaskDefinition($TaskName,$TaskDefinition,6,$null,$null,5)
```

**Conclusion:**

So I don't know what you are trying to achieve but you must be consistent with all parameters for the task creation to execute properly.

I would advise you to use SCHTASKS.exe instead of the COM object, it will be easier, less complex and it's available on Windows 7 and higher versions.

Comment: Zivkok, Thanks for your complete explanation, 
I admit that i did not take the time to work on this script so much, maybe thirty minutes but you are right, the script is now running fine !
I'll take the time to read about SCHTASKS.exe and  try to use it
Thanks again, i appreciate, really

Comment: @dst1ny, you're welcome, always glad to help :-)